# Fetch First 'Variable' Rows Only

Tags: db2

It is possible to pass value into fetch first syntax?

```
        SET inputtotalCount = inputcount - inputintSimilarityLevel;
        IF inputtotalCount > 0 THEN
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM EUSYSUPW WHERE UPRECID IN (
                SELECT UPRECID FROM EUSYSUPW
                WHERE UPUSRID = inputSACUSRID
                ORDER BY UPMODDT ASC
                FETCH FIRST inputtotalCount ROWS ONLY);
            END;
        END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can't use parameter on fetch first rows , however you can create rownumber and delete rows with row num <= parameter .I don't have your data so I added some random integers.

```
begin atomic
declare   inputtotalCount int;
declare          inputcount  int;
declare          inputintSimilarityLevel int;
declare          inputSACUSRID int;
set inputcount=9;
set inputintSimilarityLevel=2;
SET inputtotalCount = inputcount - inputintSimilarityLevel;
set inputSACUSRID=5;
    SET inputtotalCount = 7;

    IF inputtotalCount > 0 THEN

           DELETE  from (
            SELECT e.*,row_number() over (PARTITION BY UPUSRID order by UPMODDT  ) as rownum
            FROM work.EUSYSUPW e
            WHERE UPUSRID = inputSACUSRID) as a
            where rownum<=inputtotalCount;


    END IF;
end
```

second option is to create dynamic sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variable too :

```
--Declare a global variable
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE MyVar INTEGER DEFAULT 15;

--Modify value if necessary (you can do a calcul too)
SET MyVar=27;

--Delete in function of global variable
DELETE FROM EUSYSUPW f1
WHERE exists 
(
  select * from 
  (
       select f2.UPRECID, rownumber() over(order by f2.UPMODDT ASC) rang from EUSYSUPW f2
  ) f3 
  where f1.UPRECID=f3.UPRECID and f3.rang=MyVar 

);
```